# Select an item with a specific name in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list view populating with all running processes and their process ids. I am trying to have it select a specific item from the list but I cannot figure it out.

I am currently using code like below

```
ListView findListView = new ListView();

private struct ProcessInfo
{
    public int Id;
    public string ImageKey;
    public Image Image;
    public ListViewItem ListViewItem;
}

private readonly IList<ProcessInfo> m_process = new List<ProcessInfo>();
private readonly ListViewColumnSorter m_columnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();

private void materialRaisedButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item1 = findListView.FindItemWithText("notepad");
    if (item1 != null)
        MessageBox.Show("process found");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("process missing");
}
```

How could I have my program select the item automatically if it exists?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is not very clear to me. What is `findListView`? Are you simply trying to find an exact match? Are you sure the list contains "notepad" to begin with?

Comment: Find list view is called with ListView findListView = new ListView();

I am checking to make sure the item exists first, but I want to select the item automatically

Comment: https://gyazo.com/13c480d6a6f4c988f09dd571bcb9fda3 This is what I mean by selecting the item

Comment: Nowhere in the posted code are you adding to `findListView` so it is empty. Thus nothing is in that list so nothing will be found.

Comment: It is being filled with the data. I have gotten it to select the data from the second column. Now I just need it to select the row that contains the column

https://gyazo.com/391be389d590fe3b36879222ae3bd95d

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match, including case, or are you looking for a fuzzy sort of match?

Comment: You can use the `SelectItem(index)` function, where `index` is the `rowIndex` of the matching row.

Comment: I am looking for an exact match of the item

Comment: @Shanid How can I get the rowIndex with one of the column's data?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this method-

```
ListViewItem item1 = findListView.FindItemWithText("notepad");
findListView.SelectItem(findListView.Items.IndexOf(item1));
```

`findListView.Items.IndexOf(item1)` will give you the index of item with text "notepad". Then you use it to select the corresponding item in the listView.

I guess you can accomplish this in just one line, like-
`findListView.SelectItem(findListView.Items.IndexOf(findListView.FindItemWithText("notepad")));`

It doesn't need to be this long, you may find other methods also.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows Forms:

```
ListViewItem item = listViewProducts.FindItemWithText("text");
item.Selected = true;
item.EnsureVisible();
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

var3 = findListView.Items.IndexOf(findListView.SelectedIndex);